# Unwanted word wrapping in caption

Tags: fusioncharts

In a FusionCharts (version 3.4.0) 2D Bar chart, I found that the caption wraps to a second line when the bar labels are long.  How do I prevent it from doing this so that the caption appears on one line?

Check out this jsFiddle to reproduce the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/eZjjT/163/

```
-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent wrapping of caption text in horizontal bar charts, you can specify the maximum percentage of width for data labels along the X-axis, using the “maxLabelWidthPercent” attribute.